# How to register odd jobs in Linkedin.com

Tags: work-experience, linkedin

When I was young, I lived and worked in England for about two years, doing a lot of odd jobs. I would like to show this on my Linkedin.com profile. What would be the best way to put it?

Would the following be ok?

> Company Name: Odd Jobs
>
> Title: Odd Jobs
>
> Location: England

Comment: Downvotes already? If someone has lived overseas and knows their way around the English airports, train stations, and freeways this is useful to people like law firms that employ couriers.

Comment: You were working for a single company doing whatever they needed you to do at the time? Or were you essentially freelancing, doing different jobs for different people?

Comment: Bookmarking this question to show people why linkedin is a crap resource for finding employees.

Answer (score 7):

> **2008 - 2010** At various times mow lawns, deliver groceries, wash cars, babysit, clean out attics and clean swimming pools as needed.

Best thing to do is itemize these to any reasonable extent possible, since 'odd jobs' could be focused on domestic services (child care and cleaning), transportation (delivery and porter), or commercial (filling in for clerks or food servers).

Answer (score 3):

The key is the phrase in your "When I was young".

The past employment history in LinkedIn  is used several ways:

- To confirm to a potential contact that you are the Carlos Heredia they worked with 10 years ago on that project in city x for company y.
- To be used as a filter by HR searching for potential candidates,
- or to confirm the info on the resume.

I would make it match what you have on the resume/CV. If it wasn't significant enough to include on the resume/CV, then it probably isn't needed in your LinkedIn profile, unless that is how you expect old contacts to find you.

For company name I would probably use: self employed, or independent contractor.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can get people on LinkedIn to recommend you for the work you did in these part time jobs. This would go a lot further to help you get a new job than just putting it in a job listing.