# How should I list small freelance jobs on my resume?

Tags: work-experience, linkedin

A couple of years ago, I did a lot of little help jobs for handicapped people (driving, grocery shopping, cooking, etc.). None of these where with official contracts or for a company and I was paid in cash or goods.

This work experience in not related to the types of jobs I'm looking for now, but since I don't have anything interesting to put on my resume for this period, I'd like to mention it to avoid an employment gap.

Should I put this undeclared work experience on my LinkedIn profile and/or resume?

Comment: Are you worried about the legal/financial consequences of listing this work because you didn't declare them *for tax purposes* or are you asking how to describe this experience on a resume?

Comment: @Lilienthal I'm more worried about the impression it gives. I'm afraid putting a list of jobs without employers will look weird. Plus I can't prove I really did work.

Comment: Note: I'm not fluent in English, feel free to correct my grammar.

Comment: So by undeclared you mean that you don't think of it as a 9-to-5 job with an actual company, instead you were looking for and accepting short-term work independently?

Comment: @Lilienthal Yes, plus there was no signed contracts and I was paid either in cash or goods.

Comment: In that case your question is largely similar to this one: [How to register odd jobs in Linkedin.com](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12973/how-to-register-odd-jobs-in-linkedin-com). You would indeed group this kind of work in a single heading as "freelance work" or the like. Apart from being about LinkedIn rather than a resume, would you say that that question matches what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @Lilienthal Yes, the questions are very similar. I didn't know "odd jobs" meant undeclared short-term jobs, so I couldn't find it before asking. How can I mark my question as duplicate? Should I simply delete it?

Comment: Not a problem, that question wasn't very searchable. In general I'd refer to this kind of work as either freelance or temp work. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_work) shows there are quite a few synonyms you can choose from. "Eldercare" is a potential buzzword you can use if it fits but I'd suggest simply listing it on your resume as "**20## - 20##: Intermittent freelance work for the less-abled involving driving/chauffeur duties, errands, cooking, ...**"

Comment: There's no need to delete your question. I'm going to edit it to match your original question and flag it as duplicate so it will link to that question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the tax man will be looking at your Linked In Profile if that's what you're worried about, but I can't guarantee that depending on what country you're in...

I would certainly put this on my profile & CV, especially if it's relevant to the job you're trying to get, but even if it isn't if you haven't much else to put on there.

It doesn't matter that you didn't have an employer or can't prove that you worked there. Even if they look for such proof and you can't provide it, it's a lot better than putting nothing on there!

It *does* matter if you have periods on your CV where it appears you've been doing nothing. It will look a lot better if these jobs are filling that time.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can't prove you volunteered, volunteer work and community service are great things to add to your resume,  CV or a linkedin profile especially if you don’t have a lot of paid work experience .

If you have an undeclared work experience for a place where you worked for a longer period of time you can write how long you volunteered and what kind of work you did. It will look like a normal work experience but will show your unpaid work which is always a plus when it comes to experience.

From [(fortune.com)](http://fortune.com/2011/10/20/should-you-include-volunteer-work-on-a-resume/):

> Increasingly, corporate bosses like Ready are taking note of job
>   candidates’ volunteer efforts. They recognize that in the recent
>   recession, talented employees may have had stretches of unemployment
>   that they filled with unpaid work. A recent LinkedIn LNKD -0.28%
>   survey found that 41% of hiring managers consider volunteer experience
>   equally valuable as paid work.
>
> But workers still feel nervous about what experience to include and
>   how to be honest while also presenting in the best light. **LinkedIn
>   found** that 89% of professionals surveyed had volunteer experience, but
>   only 45% included it on their resume.

Comment: I worked for handicapped people I met through my aunt (who was herself physically handicapped) and was paid for it, so I can't describe it as volunteer work. (Thanks for the link though, it is interesting).